# Parse HTTP:Response object

Tags: perl, cgi, forms, lwp-useragent

I am having some difficulties getting results from a form via Perl. I believe I have successfully found the form and submitted the value I want to the appropriate field, but am unsure of how to turn the response object into something useful (If I print it out it shows up as the following).

`HTTP::Request=HASH(0x895b8ac)`

Here is the relevant code (assume $url is correct)

```
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $responce = $ua->get($url);
    my @form = HTML::Form->parse($responce);
    my $chosen = $form[0];
    $chosen->value('netid', $user);
    my $ro = $chosen->click('Search');
```

What can I do to make $ro useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [HTML::Form docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aForm)  on click:

> The result of clicking is an [HTTP::Request](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aRequest) object that can then be passed to [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) if you want to obtain the server response.

So you can do:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get($url);
my @form = HTML::Form->parse($response);
my $chosen = $form[0];
$chosen->value('netid', $user);
my $ro = $chosen->click('Search');

# If you want to see what you're sending to the server:
print $ro->as_string;

# Fetch the server's response:
$response = $ua->request($ro);
```

What you do with `$response` next depends on what you're trying to do.

P.S. "responce" is usually spelled without a C.  But HTTP does have a history of misspellings.  (I'm looking at you, "Referer".)

Comment: Ok, when I run that code I get "Can't use a HTTP::Request object as a URI". I am trying to get out the results from submitting the form

Comment: @Ross, sorry, wrong method.  You use `request` when you already have a request object.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks! That worked. Is there any way to get a listing of the fields in the results?

Comment: @Ross, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: The form result once it is sent is a page that shows the name associated with the looked up user name (hence "netid" as in network id). a few other pieces of info are given as well, but I only want the name, how can i extract that? And thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Ross, web scraping is much too complicated to answer in a comment.  Ask another question if you need help with it.  You'll have to give details about the HTML page that the server is sending you.

Comment: okay, it was a really basic page so I was able to brute force substring until just the info i wanted showed up (plus characters after, and then I chopped at an index of a character that was right after the info I wanted). thanks again for all of your help!